# how to add two data set to a grid view table

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
ds = server.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.Text, MysqlStatement, param);
ds1 = server.ExecuteQuery(CommandType.Text, getOwnMsgQuery, param);
Grid_Messagetable.DataSource =ds;
Grid_Messagetable.DataSource = ds1;
```

I have to do two different query to get data for a grid table, but in this case it is showing only result from ds1 as it is executed after ds. How can I do this. Thanks

Comment: Well what you are doing is like `int i=0; i=1; int k=i;` as a result `k` is `1`, please check Icarus's answer for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both datasets have largely the same schema, you could merge them before binding to the grid:

```
ds.Merge(ds1);
Grid_Messagetable.DataSource = ds;
```

[See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4swwh51k.aspx)